# iterating through keys of a dictionary and perform slicing on its values which are dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary which its values are "pandas data frame".
I'd like to iterate over the keys and perform slicing on the values of the keys.

```
dictionary = {'key_1':[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 6, 7, 8]], 'key_2': [[5,8,4,6],[1,5,2,6]]}
```

The final output would look like this:

```
dictionary = {'key_1':[[3,4],[7,8]], 'key_2': [[4,6], [2,6]]}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your desired result with the help of `nested for loop` AND `dict.items()` the method as given below:-

```
dictionary = {'key_1':[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 6, 7, 8]], 'key_2': [[5,8,4,6],[1,5,2,6]]} 
new_dict = {}

for key,value in dictionary.items():  # Iterating key and value
    my_list = []
    for var in value:   # Iterating over a particular value
        my_list.append( var[-1:-3:-1]  )  # Performing indexing and slicing.
    new_dict[key] = my_list   
dictionary = new_dict
print(dictionary)
```

**Output**

```
{'key_1': [[4, 3], [8, 7]], 'key_2': [[6, 4], [6, 2]]}
```

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Say if we have a list:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

... and if we want the last two elements:

```
li[-2:] ==> [3, 4]
```

How about nested list:

```
v = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 6, 7, 8]]
[li[-2:] for li in v] ==> [[3, 4], [7, 8]
```

Putting it together:

```
{k: [li[-2:] for li in v] for k, v in dictionary.items()}  # It's what you want
```